# merge 2 columns into one within same df, eliminating "0" values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I want to merge 2 columns into a new one, keeping all years from column 1, and replacing "0"s in column 1 for years in column 2:

`Column 1 (Year1): 2019, 2018,    0,    0, 2017, 2010`

`Column 2 (Year2): 2019, 2017, 2013, 2011,    0, 2010`

Expected output:

`Column 3: 2019, 2018, 2013, 2011, 2017, 2010`

Here is what I tried:

```
df['Column3']= df.pop('Column1').fillna(df.pop('Column2')).astype(int)
```

But given I have zeros "0"s in column 1, they are not being replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`df['y3'] = df['y1'].mask(df['y1'] == 0, df['y2'])`

```
     y1    y2    y3
0  2019  2019  2019
1  2018  2017  2018
2     0  2013  2013
3     0  2011  2011
4  2017     0  2017
5  2010  2010  2010
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do using [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2019, 2018, 0, 0, 2017, 2010], 'col2': [2019, 2017, 2013, 2011, 0, 2010]})

# set 0 as NA
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: None if x == 0 else x)

# create new column
df['col3'] = df['col1'].combine_first(df['col2']).astype(int)
```

You can also use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df['col3'] = (df
               .apply(lambda x: x['col1'] if x['col1'] != 0 else x['col2'], 
               axis=1)
```